# Cannot delete item from set using hibernate

Tags: hibernate, requestfactory

I have a 1 to many relationship between Report and Setting. The mapping is defined in the parent as

```
  <set name="settings" table="SETTING" inverse="true" lazy="true" fetch="select" cascade="all-delete-orphan">
        <key>
            <column name="REPORT_ID" not-null="true" />
        </key>
        <one-to-many class="net.test.domain.Setting" />
    </set>
```

And the child maps the parent like this

```
<many-to-one name="report" class="net.test.domain.Report" fetch="select" cascade="evict">
        <column name="REPORT_ID" />
    </many-to-one>
```

My test Loads a "Report", finds a "Setting", removes it from the list and calls saveOrUpdate() on the ReportDao. This works as expected, the setting is deleted.

Now the puzzling part. Calling the same method via a RequestFactory call, the record is not deleted. I see no exceptions, and the Hibernate Interceptor indicates 
1: that the onDelete() method has been called for the expected entry, 
2: that transaction.wasCommitted() == true. (In the afterTransactionCompleted() method).

All seems to be ok, but the record is not deleted from the database. I inspect the SQL output, and there are no deletes found.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem but I am now concerned of how RequestFactory and Hibernate work together.

The database tables are mapped

```
Report - Setting - Type 
and 
Report - Column - Type - Setting
```

RequestFactory has a ".with" from the Report with 2 mappings :

```
with.add("settings");
with.add("Column.Type.settings");
```

If I remove the second of those 2 `.with` statements, the `Set<Settings>` is successfully persisted to the database. If I have both, then hibernate interceptor tells me its going to delete it, but it doesnt, as stated in the original post.

I find this very troubling. 
Why should a `.with` have this effect? 
Why does the interceptor tell me it will delete, and `tx.isCommitted()` when it does not delete?